# What is Service Worker Console? & Where is it in Chrome Browser?

Tags: javascript, web-services, google-chrome, console.log, service-worker

I am working on push notifications and came upon an unfamiliar term:

`service worker console.`

I have read and used the term `console log` or `web console` in browser, but I am not familier with the term `service worker console`, and I didn't find appropriate answer after [googling it](https://www.google.com/search?q="service+worker+console").

Can anyone explain what is `service worker console`? How to access it in Google Chrome?

Comment: Where did you see it? Can you provide a link, or copy-and-paste the context?

Comment: I have not heard of the term. But service workers are to replace the appcache, you could try to look at `Developer tools -> Resources` in Chrome. Also it's possible it is only available in some dev/beta build of Chrome.

Comment: Read the last paragraph of this article http://craig-russell.co.uk/2016/01/29/service-worker-messaging.html#.V77FjXV97qM

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Go to chrome://serviceworker-internals

Choose any service worker and start it if not already started.

Click on Inspect!!

Boom! You have the console there!

Comment: Thank you very much you have solved my head ache. Can you further guide me in my project web pusher if you have time.

Comment: Yeah sure @SaugatBhattarai :). Keep posting whatever doubts you come across!

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to get unique identification of browser? I need to push message to unique browser. I am confused how to do it.

Comment: Any idea why inspect shows empty logs even though service worker status is active, and running?

Comment: Are you sure you're `console.log`-ing something when your events fire? @NuruddinIminokhunov

Comment: `chrome://serviceworker-internals` is old, and being replaced by the standard dev tools.

Comment: Hello, in a recent Chrome version : chrome://inspect/#service-workers

Answer (score 14):

If a page has a service worker, then that service worker's logs show in that page's JavaScript console. You can see the source of a log line on the right-hand side of the log:

[image: log line sources]

In the console, there is a select box to select the *JavaScript context*. This defaults to `top` (which means "show everything"), but you can select a more specific context for just the service worker:

[image: selecting alternative context]

Comment: Thanks! This seems like a much easier approach than the accepted answer, may also be worth noting that `self.console.log` [is needed](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1482) from certain parts of the worker.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Go to Preference setting on chrome browserin Ubuntu use **Shift + ?** or **F1** then uncheck **Hide Network message** and selected context only.
Then restart your tab.